# Вызов одинаковых методов разных классов, дженерики

Tags: java

Есть два метода

```
private NsiRef getServiceType(JPenalty jPenalty) 
{
    NsiRef serviceType = new NsiRef();
    serviceType.setCode(jPenalty.getServiceTypeNSI().getCode());
    serviceType.setGUID(jPenalty.getServiceTypeNSI().getGuid());
    return serviceType;
}
```

и

```
private NsiRef getServiceType(JBillDetail jBillDetail) 
{
    NsiRef serviceType = new NsiRef();
    serviceType.setCode(jBillDetail.getServiceTypeNSI().getCode());
    serviceType.setGUID(jBillDetail.getServiceTypeNSI().getGuid());
    return serviceType;
}
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать один через дженерики.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`JPenalty` и `JBillDetail` должны реализовать общий интерфейс с методом `getServiceTypeNSI()` и тогда можно будет использовать один метод с этим интерфейсом:

```
private NsiRef getServiceType(SomeInterface var) 
{
    NsiRef serviceType = new NsiRef();
    serviceType.setCode(var.getServiceTypeNSI().getCode());
    serviceType.setGUID(var.getServiceTypeNSI().getGuid());
    return serviceType;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, такой вариант подходит.